# Get Firestore documents of a collection by document ID (Python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In Python I am using the firebase_admin python sdk to query the Firestore database.

I want to get the documents of a collection by filtering the document_id, however I did not find any working solution. I found a lot of users saying that I need to use FieldPath, however it is not in the firebase_admin package.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
   from firebase_admin import firestore
   from google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path import FieldPath

   numbers_collection_ref = (
        firestore.client()
        .collection("numbers")
    )


    filtered_numbers_docs_ref = numbers_collection_ref.where(
        filter=FieldFilter(
            FieldPath.document_id(),
            ">=",
            "3",
        )
    )
```

This always returns 0 documents.
I already do this in another project in Flutter and there it works.

To answer Frank, I can explain it like this:
I have a collection numbers with 10 documents,
document with document_id: 1
document with document_id: 2
document with document_id: 3
and so on

I would expect to get the documents with document ids 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10. However it returns exactly 0 documents.

I execute the query by doing filtered_numbers_docs_ref.get()

Comment: "however it is not in the firebase_admin package" That should be: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path.FieldPath. In fact, if your code doesn't generate an error (but "just" returns no results) it seems that the `FieldPath` object *is* found.

Comment: Note though that a document ID is a string, so the ">=" may not do what you expect it to do. Can you show a screenshot (from the Firestore console) of the document(s) that you'd expect your code to return?

Comment: It'd also help to see how you actually execute the query and what you do with the results, i.e. maybe log the number of results you get.

Comment: I answered by editing the post, thanks

Comment: Please provide: 1) a **screenshot** of the Firebase console of the documents you expect to get back. Keep in mind here that document IDs are strings and thus lexicographically ordered, and in that order `"10"` comes before `"3"`. This would apply to a regular field with a string value too btw, but just to a document ID. 2) The code that we can run that prints one value, but you'd expect another value. Include both the code and the values.